# How to add comma separated list for the select list check box field type

Tags: nodes

For my one site, I added a select list(text) > check box field type to my content. When I go to manage display tab(using display suite module), in the format column column for the field, I see drop down field with 4 values ( css class, default, key, list). I selected list. Next to that I also see a geared setting where it allows me to make a comma separated list. When I go to front end, I see the values listed separated by commas. It works fine.

I am trying to do the same thing for my other site. But as for the drop down field, I only see default and key. Also, I don't see the geared setting icon to make it comma separated list. I am not sure what I did wrong on my second site. Both site have the same field type.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the [Text list formatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/textformatter) module installed on the first site, but not the second site? That would provide the functionality you describe.

Comment: I dont have the text list formatter in any of the sites installed.

Comment: How about any module with "format" in it? Like https://www.drupal.org/project/textformatter or https://www.drupal.org/project/custom_formatters

Comment: In site 1, I found 'Field formatter CSS class 7.x-1.3' and '
 Text formatter 7.x-1.3 ' installed and enabled. I did not have these two in site 2. Now, I installeda and enabled both into site 2. I see the css in the drop down field but I still dont see list yet.

Comment: On the Text Formatter module page, it mentions a textformatter_contrib module. Maybe you need to enable that? (I haven't tried the module): "The Drupal 7 version has been refactored to include hooks to implement any field types. There is now a textformatter_contrib module to contain these additional implementations. Currently entityreference, link, node reference and user reference fields are included. "